# How to use SQlite manager in chrome

Tags: sqlite, google-chrome

I am trying to use SQlite manager with my chrome browser . 
How can i download SQlite manager extension ?? 
I have already use SQLite with firefox ..

is there any alternative option ??

Comment: this question is not related to programming. please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1):

You can use the new WebExtension-based "[SQLite Manager](https://add0n.com/sqlite-manager.html)" extension. It is avaiable for both [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager-webext/) and [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sqlite-manager/njognipnngillknkhikjecpnbkefclfe)